# Can I have an array with indeterminate length in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, initialization

so I am a beginner in c, and I am doing this program where a user input values in an array and if the value is 101 then the program is finished. the thing is I don't want the length of the array to be initialized, rather when the user enter 101 there would be the last value and the last place in the array. for example they entered 101 in the third place then the length of the array would be 4. I don't know if that possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {

  int i,j;
  int a[i];

 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
   printf("Enter Value Nummber %d:",i);
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);


   if 
     (a[i] == 101) break;
     else continue;


 }
```

Here I put the max length could be 10 but, if the user for example gives just 4 values and then 101 then it gives the rest of spots garbage values.

Comment: Firstly: `int a[i]` is wrong because `i` has not been set at that point so contains random garbage. As to your question, you can use dynamic allocation function `realloc` to continuously increase the array size by 1. But that is generally not the way it is done as it is inefficient to continuously re-size the array. Normally a max size is set and then keep track of how many entries in the array have been filled in.

Comment: Regarding "how does it work", the answer is that it *doesn't* work. The value of `i` will be *indeterminate*, it could be any seemingly random or garbage value, including zero or one million or minus ten thousand or something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

In this case

```
  int a[i];
```

is called a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and you're using `i` unitialized, and that can invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to have a defined value of `i` before you can use it.

That said, the cleaner approach will be (without using dynamic allocation and re-sizing)

- Define a higher limit (`#define MAXLEN 100`) and use that to create an array, and initialize it to a value (say, `0`).
- Keep on asking user for the inputs, until (whichever is earlier)

  - You get a value `101`
  - Counter reaches `MAXLEN`

Otherwise, if you're okay with using allocated memory ([`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)/ [`realloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) and family), then:

- Define a starting size (`#define INITSIZ 32`)
- Allocate memory for that size using `malloc()`.
- Ask user for inputs.
- If you get an input value of `101`, `free()` the allocated memory and exit.
- Otherwise, once you hit the size, double the allocation using `realloc()` and continue to previous step.

Comment: @4386427 how VLA is going to help here? It still cant be resized, right? and anyways, user is not going to provide array dimension, so...

Comment: @4386427 Ah OK, sure

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a look at [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). It allows you to dynamically allocate memory and gives you a pointer to the start of the allocated piece of memory.

You can access an element with a pointer that points to the first element and then increase the pointer every time you add a value. Unlike other languages, C does not prevent you from accessing values outside of an array, so track the number of items added with a counter, and make sure to stay within your allocated memory (so save the length in a variable). You can then replace the for loop with an infinite loop, and `break` once the user inputs the value `101`. When you reach the limit of your allocated memory, you can allocate a new array twice the size (so make sure to save the length in a variable) and copy the previous array there, then [free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the first array.

Comment: True, I edited my answer to be clearer about arrays and pointers. I think that going more into detail won't help the OP at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> "*Can I have an array with indeterminate length?*"
>
> I don't want the length of the array to be initialized, rather when the user enter 101 there would be the last value and the last place in the array. For example they entered 101 in the third place then the length of the array would be 4. I don't know if that possible.

No, it is not possible.

```
int a[i];
```

You cannot write to an indeterminate array, as `i` is not initialized - it holds a garbage value.

Any such attempt is undefined behavior and doesn´t make much sense.

How do you want to store the value the user puts in to the *assumed* third element if there has not been space allocated for it?

Of course you can use VLAs or allocate and reallocate dynamic memory (as the other two answers suggest) but you can´t write data to memory which isn´t allocated for storing that values.

I do not understand your idea behind. Maybe you explain the bigger goal you want to achieve.